# Unchecking a radio button

Tags: android, if-statement, radio-button

The application is a step sequencer application with 16 radio groups with 8 buttons in each group. It works perfectly except once a group has a button selected I cant turn it off unless I use the clear button I have created to clear all radiogroups. What I would like to add is some code that says when a selected radio button is selected again it simply turns off like a toggle. I tried using toggles but then other issues arose with that method. Below is an attempt at it but it is way off the mark Im guessing

```
final RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
RadioButton lC1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RadioButtonlowC1);

Button D1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.RadioButtonD1);
        D1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PdBase.sendFloat("D1", 74);
                int selectedTypeId = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton D1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedTypeId);
                if(radioGroup1 != null) // This will be null if none of the radio buttons are selected
                       radioGroup1.clearCheck(); 
                PdBase.sendFloat("D1", 0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the button in a radio group, then clear the group.  A radio button can't be unchecked directly, because the idea is that one option in a group is always checked.

Comment: It is in a radio group sorry and I have a button that does clear all of the buttons but that is for all radio groups. Actually I'll try and use that code more specifically for each group as well.

Comment: Actually this wont work for me as I need to be able to switch within the radiogroup to different buttons

Comment: Given complete code... Now when the application loaded it will reset and make sure that none of the radiobuttons is selected. Once the application is loaded in my system I am able to select the file.

Comment: I disagree that "the idea [of a radio group] is that one option in a group is **always** checked." The idea is to enforce mutual exclusion. No more than one option can be selected at a time but not having a selection is still perfectly valid. Groups have no selection by default and as you mentioned, a group's selection can be cleared programmatically (as the result of pressing a button for example.) The question is merely asking for a way to clear a group as the result of a different action - tapping a selected <RadioButton> button instead of a adding a "clear" <Button>. See my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to create radiogroup, radiobutton and how to use in Java code. Hope it will give you complete picture

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/maptype"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/satellite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

**In Java Code**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    RadioGroup rgrpMapType = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.maptype);
    int selectedTypeId = rgrpMapType.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton rbMapType = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedTypeId);
    if(rbMapType != null) // This will be null if none of the radio buttons are selected
           rgrpMapType.clearCheck(); 
}
```

Comment: After line 3 in the above java code write this code. rbMapType will be null only if some radio button is selected. Hope the code it clear. if(rbMapType != null)
    rgrpMapType.clearCheck();

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it wont let me select the radio buttons when I implement the code you gave me this is how it looks after adding your code

Comment: Couldnt get a fix so Im just going to add a clear button for each group