# Android radio button uncheck

Tags: android, radio-button

The application is a step sequencer application with 16 radio groups with 8 buttons in each group. It works perfectly except once a group has a button selected I cant turn it off unless I use the clear button I have created to clear all radiogroups. What I would like to add is some code that says when a selected radio button is selected again it simply turns off like a toggle. I tried using toggles but then other issues arose with that method. Below are two attempts but both simply stops me using the button

```
final RadioGroup radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
RadioButton D1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButtonD1);

Button D1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RadioButtonD1);
D1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        PdBase.sendFloat("D1", 74);
        int selectedTypeId = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RadioButton D1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedTypeId);
        if (D1 != null) // This will be null if none of the radio buttons are selected
            radioGroup1.clearCheck();
        PdBase.sendFloat("D1", 0);
    }
});

RadioButton lC1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButtonlowC1);
lC1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick (View v) {
        int selectedTypeId = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        RadioButton lC1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButtonlowC1);
        if (selectedTypeId == -1) {
            PdBase.sendFloat("lC1", 72);
        }
        else if (selectedTypeId == R.id.RadioButtonlowC1) {
            radioGroup1.clearCheck();
            PdBase.sendFloat("lC1", 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do not you just add an OFF button to each group?

Comment: This isn't usually how `RadioButtons` work and not what people expect. You should add a `RadioButton` like `none` to your group

Comment: I could do that but as it is monophonic I want only one selected in each group

Comment: Having a clear button for each group would work but not be very practical

Comment: You will only get one selected in each group anyway. That is how radio buttons work. Your problem from a design perspective is that you are effectively using no button selected as an extra condition, which you have no way of toggling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unchecking a radio button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821334/unchecking-a-radio-button)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recently had the same need - to have a radio group where the selected item could be deselected by tapping it again.  I found that I couldn't accomplish that using listeners but I *was* able to do it using a custom `RadioButton`, like so...

```
public class ToggleableRadioButton extends RadioButton {
    // Implement necessary constructors

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if(isChecked()) {
            if(getParent() instanceof RadioGroup) {
                ((RadioGroup)getParent()).clearCheck();
            }
        } else {
            setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the button is toggled in different ways depending on its current state - i.e., calling `setChecked(true)` on the button vs. calling `clearCheck()` on the group.  If `setChecked()` is used in both cases, a button that was just deselected cannot be immediately re-selected - the logic in `RadioGroup` seems to immediately deselect it.

To use this button, just replace your `<RadioButton>` tags with `<your.package.ToggleableRadioButton>` in your layout XML.

Comment: getting ERROR when i implementing the constructor
**LOGCAT:- ToggleableRadioButton.<init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]**

Answer (score 7):

I just used the answer from [@spaaarky21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/515205/spaaarky21)

and my full code look like this and it is working fine!

Java Class

```
public class ToggleableRadioButton extends RadioButton {


    public ToggleableRadioButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ToggleableRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ToggleableRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ToggleableRadioButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if(isChecked()) {
            if(getParent() instanceof RadioGroup) {
                ((RadioGroup)getParent()).clearCheck();
            }
        } else {
            setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

And for the XML layout

```
<com.smart_dent.adapters.ToggleableRadioButton android:id="@+id/tejido_blando_perfil_convexo"
                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:text="@string/tejido_blando_convexo_label" />
```

In this case you just need to change the package, I this is easy to find, it is just at the top of the Java Class Flie (if you created it from Android Studio)

Answer (score 5):

It actually **can** be done with listeners but with an `OnTouchListener`, which will trigger before the button's state has changed, instead of the usual `OnClickListener`. The following works for me:

```
View.OnTouchListener radioButtonOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (((RadioButton) v).isChecked()) {
            // If the button was already checked, uncheck them all
            radioGroup.clearCheck();
            // Prevent the system from re-checking it
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
radioButton1.setOnTouchListener(radioButtonOnTouchListener);
radioButton2.setOnTouchListener(radioButtonOnTouchListener);
```

Where `radioGroup` is the parent of `radioButton1` and `radioButton2`

Comment: `onTouch()` is fairly low level. It seems like this would deselect the button for gestures other than a tap/click.

Comment: Hmm, good point, @spaaarky21. I guess we should also check that the event is of type `ACTION_DOWN`. Although, testing this, I haven't been able to trigger anything that seemed abnormal

Answer (score 4):

Edit from @spaaarky21 answer

```
@Override
public void toggle() {
    if (isChecked()) {
        if (getParent() instanceof RadioGroup) {
            ((RadioGroup) getParent()).clearCheck();
        } 
        // add else here when a single radioButton without radioGroup
        else {
            setChecked(false);
        }
    } else {
        setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also doing the job:

```
public final class ToggleAbleRadioButton extends AppCompatRadioButton {
  public ToggleAbleRadioButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override public void toggle() {
    setChecked(!isChecked());
  }
}
```

Comment: not work, if you check twice it's not checked again, because thos code in appCompatRadioButoon - if (mBroadcasting) {
                return;
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean to toggle the button on and off.

Add a boolean somewhere in your code:

```
var radioButton1IsSelected = false
```

Then setup the onClickListener for the button:

```
radioButton1.setOnClickListener {
        radioButton1IsSelected = !radioButton1IsSelected
        radioButton1.isChecked = radioButton1IsSelected
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kotlin version of the custom `ToggleableRadioButton` to uncheck without needing to use `RadioGroup`.

```
class ToggleableRadioButton constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) :
        AppCompatRadioButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    constructor(context: Context) : this(context, null)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : this(context, attrs, 0)

    override fun toggle() {
        isChecked = !isChecked
    }
}
```

With its default settings, i.e. `super.toggle()` does not uncheck since it is explicitly controlled by the `RadioButton.java`

[image: RadioButton Toggle Source Code]

As it is stated in the documentation, if the radio button is already checked, the toggle will not be called.